# SSIS видит ограниченное количество столбцов в csv файле

Tags: sql-server, integration-services

Существует CSV файл из которого идёт импорт SSIS пакетом.
В CSV файле 117 столбцов. SSIS видит намного меньше.
SQL Server 2012, MS Visual Studio 2012. Существует ли способ обойти это ограничение?

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста метку SSIS. У меня рейтинга не хватает.

Comment: Добавил "integration-services" - "ssis" можно добавить только как синоним к ней, и то только тот, у кого есть 5 балов репутации по этой метке.

Comment: Версия SQL Server? Вы уверены что ограничение именно по количеству столбцов, а не символов в первой строке? Просто есть известная проблема при чтении строк с более чем 8000 символов.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос: SQL Server 2012, MS Visual Studio 2012.